# Postman Windows Authentication (NTLM) not working

Tags: postman, asp.net-core-webapi, windows-authentication, ntlm-authentication

I have created a brand new WebAPI project from Visual Studio template. Target Framework `netcoreapp3.1`. I have configured it with **windows authentication**. I created a request in Postman with NTLM configuration to call my API. When I debug my application and call the request via Postman I get the following error:

**`IIS 10.0 Detailed Error - 401.1 - Unauthorized`**

**My Startup class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**My Controller class:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries =
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

        public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            var rng = new Random();
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                    TemperatureC = rng.Next(-20, 55),
                    Summary = Summaries[rng.Next(Summaries.Length)]
                })
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**launchSettings.json**:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:52109",
      "sslPort": 44396
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "WebApplication1": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "weatherforecast",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Postman config with result:**
[image]

**Postman auth config:**
[image]

I have no clue what's the problem :-( I have called my API from Insomnia or SoapUI and it works just fine! Maybe my problem is related to that issue https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8038

Comment: Does your password have any special character like `+` in the end?

Comment: No only a "-" inside!

Comment: Can you change your password so that it doesn't contain any special characters and then try again?

Comment: No because of our internal password policy!

Comment: Did you resolved this issue? I have the similar situation. The Api is working good in browser, Postman Chrome extension but not in Postman app or the consuming application.

Comment: No I switched to Insomnia (https://insomnia.rest/download) where it worked with windows authentication.