# Windows Authentication - Postman (HttpContext Name is Null)

Tags: api, authentication, .net-core, windows-authentication, authenticationchallenge

My question is similar to [Postman Windows Authentication (NTLM) not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62047306/postman-windows-authentication-ntlm-not-working) but there are no answers to it so far.

I have used a .NetCore rest api (netcoreapp3.1).

1. In launchsettings.json

   ```
   {
    "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": true,
    "anonymousAuthentication": false,
   ..
   }
   ```
2. Startup.cs

   ```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
     services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
   }

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {

        //...
      app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        //....useEndpoints middleware is being called afterwards

      }
   ```
3. EmployeeController.cs

   ```
   [Route("IISDetails")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult IISDetails()
    {

        var name = User.Identity.Name;
        return new ContentResult() { Content = $@"IIS authorized. AD: {name}" };
    }
   ```

I have not used [Authorize] tag so that atleast i can see if this works but Name is always null.

Postman I am setting username in Authorization tab. Image attached for reference.

[image]

If I put Authorize attribute to my IISDetails function it gives me

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I added [Authorization] tag and changed Startup.cs from

```
services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

to

> services.AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Negotiate.NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();

Tried it in the browser and it worked!!

P.S: Still not working with Postman **NTLM Authentication (Beta)**

- On IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, its giving me

> System.InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action configureOptions).
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.ChallengeAsync(HttpContext context, String scheme, AuthenticationProperties properties)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

Still any guidance on why the other things are not working is appreciated :)